# Give more weight to high frequency words

Tags: elasticsearch

Our elasticsearch documents are short medical terms, there are a lot words are very high frequent, like "history", "left", "right", "open", "closed" etc.

Since by default **BM25** is favoring less frequent terms, the high frequency words carry so little weight sometimes they're close to being ignored, but those words are important, like "open fracture" and "closed fracture" are much different in the meaning.

We have tried to tweak the **b/k** value for the BM25 config, it works well for very short terms(<10 words). However, for terms with more than 10 words, we still run into issues with those high frequency words are being ignored. Also lowering b/k value too much hurts other search results.

The question is: **are there other ways to give more weight to those high frequency words**?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found anything that helps? [This article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables) might help you understand BM25 better. Also, one idea is to build upon the concept of opposite words (open vs closed), for example by excluding documents that contain the opposite of the search word.

Comment: We used tokenization rule to partially solve the issue. for example `open fracture` will be tokenized as `open_fracture` and `fracture`, `left knee` will be tokenized as `left_knee` and `knee`. Since high frequency word usually doesn't carry full meaning by itself, this works for our use case.

Comment: Nice that's a smart solution. You could add that as an answer here for future visitors.